# VALUE parameter cannot be parsed to number (Google SpreadSheet Error)

Tags: parsing, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula, instagram

I`m trying to extract from this url: https://www.instagram.com/fcbarcelona/ the value of posts amount, this one: http://prntscr.com/p29wqn using this formula in google spreadsheet:

```
=VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(A25,"//meta[@name='description']/@content"),"(?:Following, )(.{1,})(?: Posts)"))
```

but i get this massage:

Error
VALUE parameter '12.1k' cannot be parsed to number.

Tell please how could I fix the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is happening as you are passing the string that does have a non-numeric value to the `VALUE` method, which expects only numeric string.

If you really want to convert `12.1k` to number then you can do something like below (consider that the value `12.1k` is stored in `B20` cell)

```
=VALUE(IF(MID(B20,LEN(B20),1)="k",MID(B20,1,LEN(B20)-1)*1000,B20))
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]